# Tower of hanoi, python -> scheme, shows error. What am I missing?

Tags: python, scheme, towers-of-hanoi

The python implementation

```
import sys

def move(src, dst, tmp, num):
    if num == 1: print 'Move from', src, 'to', dst
    else:
        move(src, tmp, dst, num-1)
        move(src, dst, tmp, 1)
        move(tmp, dst, src, num-1)

move('left', 'right', 'middle', int(sys.argv[1]))
```

Gives the right solution for tower of hanoi. But my scheme port,

```
(define move
    (lambda (src dst tmp num)
      (if (= num 1) (printf "Move from ~s to ~s \n" src dst)
          ((move src tmp dst (- num 1))
           (move src dst tmp 1)
           (move tmp dst src (- num 1))))))
```

Gives the right solution but in the end throws the following error.

```
procedure application: expected procedure, given: #<void>; arguments were: #<void> #<void>
```

I know that its my print statement that is throwing the error, but I can't figure out why is this happening ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 ((move src tmp dst (- num 1))
  (move src dst tmp 1)
  (move tmp dst src (- num 1)))
```

The above code doesn't do what you think it does :)

To execute a series of expressions / statements you need something like this:

```
((λ ()
  (move src tmp dst (- num 1))
  (move src dst tmp 1)
  (move tmp dst src (- num 1))))
```

The *syntactic sugar* in Scheme is

```
(begin
   (move ...)
   (move ...)
   (move ...)
   ...)
```

---

```
((move ...) (move ...) (move ...))
```

will be evaluated, and the code seems to work. But as soon as the recursion ends,
the interpreter will try to execute it as `(op param1 param2)` and there is where
you get the error  `#<void>; arguments were: #<void> #<void>`

Comment: The syntactic sugar is `(begin (move ...) (move ...) ...)`